# Load TCP New Reno protocol

Tags: ubuntu, tcp

I am doing some test of the congestion control protocols and I cannot find how to load the protocol New Reno. I loaded a lot of protocols like Reno, Vegas, Hybla, Bic, Cubic, etc using the sysctl command:

```
# sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_congestion_control=<algorithm>
```

Could you help me with how to load the New Reno protocol?

Thanks in advance!